# Can a personal cloud storage device be used for syncing OneNote?

Tags: hard-drive, nas, storage, cloud-computing

*(Please note this is a question about a type of NAS (Network Attached Storage) **device**, not an online cloud storage service.)*

If I understand it correctly, a **personal cloud storage device** ([for example the My Cloud by WD)](http://www.pcmag.com/article2/0,2817,2424967,00.asp) is basically a simplified type of NAS, as a network-accessible external HDD that is not attached to a computer.

Having one seems like an ideal alternative to online cloud services, because instead of my private/work data sitting on companies' servers, it's in my living room.  I want to maintain control of my files, for the security of keeping them private.

My primary purpose of this would be to sync OneNote between multiple computers - without using Microsoft's OneDrive online "cloud" servers.

My secondary purpose is to have access to files and databases from any of my family's computers - functioning similar to Dropbox.

I have several questions about these devices, as they are somewhat different from other NAS.

- Has anyone had experience attempting to use OneNote through a personal cloud device?
- Can files be accessed just like an external HDD?
- Do the sync functions work like Dropbox?
- How do you choose a drive?
- How secure are they really - if another person tries to access it?

I would also welcome suggestions on how to approach purchasing a personal cloud device - what attributes to look for, to be sure it will work for syncing OneNote and accessing files away from home.

*I have carefully read through threads about NAS and clouds and not found this question yet.  I appreciate any help refining this question as well.  Thank you.*

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to mount the NAS via URL, IP or UNC to be a Windows share or mapped drive. This should give you the OneNote access you require.

http://www.wdc.com/wdproducts/library/UM/ENG/4779-705103.pdf

WD My Cloud manual link.

Many NAS devices also come with the ability to connect to the device remotely. If your device doesn't then you could set up a home VPN and access the files as if you were at home.